# If radio box checked OR select menu changed run custom js function

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I am trying to run a function that only executes when either:
1) One of the radio checkboxes has been selected/changed
   OR
2) When the select menu has been changed

I have the logic for both..

```
jQuery('.myselect').change(function(e) {
  alert('do something');
});

jQuery('mycheckbox:checked').each(function() {
  alert('do something');
});
```

how do I amend this to run the alert() if either the select has been changed OR a radio box has been selected/changed?

*Update*
This seems to work..
put the do_ajax class on both the select & checkboxes and run the following.

```
    jQuery('.do_ajax').change(function(e) {
          alert('do something');
    });
```

Comment: The code above is simply a guide.. I want it to done in a single statement... e.g
if ('radiobox checked' OR 'select menu change') {
  alert('do something');
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
jQuery('.myselect').change(function(e) {
    method();
});

jQuery('mycheckbox:checked').each(function (){
    method();
});


function method(){
   alert('do something');
}
```

I think you have to call same function in two case

Answer (score 0):

While you've already accepted an answer, at the time of my writing this answer, I'd suggest the following might be a better fit, since the way the question is *written* suggests that you want the `change` event to trigger an action, as opposed to iterating through the `:checked` radio-`input` elements and *then* triggering that action. That said, I'd suggest using the `on()` method, bound to multiple elements:

```
function logThis(e){
    console.log("You triggered the " + e.type + " event on a " + e.target.tagName.toLowerCase() + " element.");
}

$('select, input[type="radio"]').on('change', function(e){
    logThis(e);
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/LwJbc/).

References:

- [Attribute-equals (`[attribute="value"]`) selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/).
- [`change()`](http://api.jquery.com/change/).